# CentOS What's Taking Up My Memory?

Tags: linux, memory, centos

I'm running a KVM on CentOS 6. I have 387GB installed on the machine with 186GB allocated by VM's (I've verified this via virsh). I should have 201GB free. However, when I look at available memory I'm seeing this:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:        387776     377811       9964     193828          7     193924
-/+ buffers/cache:     183880     203895
Swap:         2047         17       2030
```

I cleared the cache using:

```
 echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

But this has no effect on the memory usage. The current running processes aren't taking up the space:

```
UID   PID %MEM
  107  5738 36.2
  107 30107  3.2
  107 29202  3.2
  107 38436  2.1
  107 34597  0.5
  107 12444  0.3
  107 15727  0.3
  107 12128  0.3
    0 10913  0.0
    0 31048  0.0
    0 10547  0.0
    0 10768  0.0
    0  2819  0.0
    0  2817  0.0
```

How can I determine what's taking up my memory and/or free up the memory that's being used?

Comment: Try running the 'top' command, it will tell you %CPU and %MEM and lots of other wonderful metrics.

Answer (score 0):

You have 203GB of free/available memory (free + buffer + cache). Of which 193GB is used as cache. So everything is fine.